# PHP: Show Only the First Letter of Each Word + Include Punctuation

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the below code to display only the first letter of each word in my string. For example, "Hello World!" would be displayed as "H W". However, I want to also include punctuation like this: "H W!"

How can I modify my code so punctuation is preserved?

```
$editversetext = preg_split("/[\s,_-]+/", $editversetext);
$initials = "";


foreach ($editversetext as $w) {
  $initials .= $w[0];

}
$initials = implode(' ',str_split($initials));
echo $initials . ".";
```

Comment: Try [`preg_replace('~\b(\p{L})\p{L}*(\p{P}?)~u', '$1$2', $s)`](https://regex101.com/r/ljVRkm/1)

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex to match what you need:

```
'~\b(\p{L})\p{L}*(\p{P}?)~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ljVRkm/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\p{L})` - Capturing group #1: a letter
- `\p{L}*` - 0+ letters
- `(\p{P}?)` - Capturing group #2: an optional punctuation (NOTE: if you also want to match symbols, replace `\p{P}` with `[\p{P}\p{S}]`)
- `u` - the "Unicode" modifier that enables PCRE_UTF and PCRE_UCP verbs to fully enable Unicode support.

Depending on the input you have, you may either use a *replacing* approach, or you may collect the matches and then combine them into the result you need in a similar way you are doing it now.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/XE0sUg):

```
$str = 'Hello World!';
// Replacing approach (if all words are matches):
echo preg_replace('~\b(\p{L})\p{L}*(\p{P}?)~u', '$1$2', $str) . "\n"; // => H W!

// Collecting/post-processing (if there are non-matching sequences)
$res = [];
preg_replace_callback('~\b(\p{L})\p{L}*(\p{P}?)~u', function($m) use (&$res) {
        $res[] = $m[1].$m[2];
        return '';
    }, $str);
print_r(implode(" ", $res)); // => H W!
```

Answer (score 0):

To match and remove all [word characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) that are not the first one, use `\B` a non [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
$str = preg_replace('/\B\w+/', "", $str);
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zh5kh9/1) or [PHP demo](http://codepad.org/BJjiL5vd)

Be aware that digitis belong to `\w`. Use `[A-Za-z]` or unicode `\pL` with `u` flag instead if desired.